# Formula for populating multiple rows using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use a formula in Google Sheets to lookup a key and populate a set of rows based on the key match. For example, I want to search Column A for the number 2 and get all the rows that have the number 2 and the corresponding column values. I want to do this in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like FILTER or QUERY should work.  See if these work as you want:

`=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z,Sheet1!A:A=2)`

`=QUERY(Sheet1!A:Z,"where A=2")`